# Counting votes and if user voted in MySQL table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 3 MySQL tables:

Features table:

```
id    name
----------
 1    feature 1
 2    feature 2
 3    feature 3
 4    feature 4
 5    feature 5
```

Votes table:

```
userid featureid
----------------
1       1
1       2
1       3
1       4
2       1
2       2
2       3
2       4
3       1
3       2
3       3
4       1
```

Users table:

```
id  name
--------
 1  John
 2  Alice
 3  Bob
 4  Mark
 5  Jane
 6  Mary
 7  Ann
```

I need to fetch in single query:

- always all features, regardless if they have votes or not
- each feature must be listed only once regardless of number of votes even if it has no votes
- votes count for each feature listed
- a special mark if currently logged user voted for current feature in the list - for example if user 3 is logged in, then list all features with votes count for all users and if user 3 voted for some features have a special field indicating his vote or NULL if he didn't (other data from votes table must be included too so it needs to be LEFT JOINED)

So far I did this:

```
SELECT *,(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM votes WHERE votes.featureid=features.id) AS "votecnt"
FROM features
LEFT JOIN votes ON votes.featureid=features.id
LEFT JOIN users ON users.id=votes.userid
GROUP BY features.id
```

It lists all features but has no special field if user 3 voted. I tried with IF, various WHERE conditions and after a lot of tries... ran out of ideas.

Desired output might look like this:

```
features.id  features.name  votes.userid  votes.otherfields  users.id  users.name
     1         feature 1          4             -                4        Mark
     2         feature 2        NULL            -              NULL       NULL
     3         feature 3        NULL            -              NULL       NULL
     4         feature 4        NULL            -              NULL       NULL      
     5         feature 5        NULL            -              NULL       NULL
```

All the features are listed and only those where user 4 voted have other joined tables filled, others are simply NULL. If someone else voted for feature 2 it is still NULL as it is of no relevance for user 4 because in this example user 4 is logged in.

Here is the problem:

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c3d10/3

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c3d10/4

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c3d10/5

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c3d10/6

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c3d10/7

All of above queries in SQLFiddle it should output all 5 features regardless of the userid. So the query must be modified somehow to show all features - even if other people voted for a feature or if there are no votes or if current user voted for feature.

Comment: can you show your desired result in tabular format?

Comment: sqlfiddle.com and your desired result

Comment: `features.id = 4` is voted only by one person, now what if a feature is voted by multiple users, how will the `votes.userid` looked like? CSV on id? What if `users.id = 3` has logged in? What is the result?

Comment: hold on.. making sqlfiddle

Comment: ok, fiddle is ready... links in the main post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're asking to have all features returned, all counts returned, but only user information if they voted for that feature.

I get the results you're looking for if you specify the userid

```
select f.id
, f.name
, u.id
, u.name
, v.votecnt
from features f
left join (select featureid, COUNT(userid) votecnt from votes group by featureid) v on v.featureid = f.id
left join votes v1 on v1.featureid = f.id and v1.userid = 4
left join users u on u.id = v1.userid
```

I chose to specify the userid inside the left join to the votes.  Anywhere else and it limits the total number of rows returned.

Results:

```
1   feature 1   4   Mark    4
2   feature 2   NULL    NULL    3
3   feature 3   NULL    NULL    3
4   feature 4   NULL    NULL    2
5   feature 5   NULL    NULL    NULL
```

Example with "Bob"

```
select f.id
, f.name
, u.id
, u.name
, v.votecnt
from features f
left join (select featureid, COUNT(userid) votecnt from votes group by featureid)v on v.featureid = f.id
left join votes v1 on v1.featureid = f.id and v1.userid = 3
left join users u on u.id = v1.userid
```

Results:

```
1   feature 1   3   Bob 4
2   feature 2   3   Bob 3
3   feature 3   3   Bob 3
4   feature 4   NULL    NULL    2
5   feature 5   NULL    NULL    NULL
```

Comment: In your query if you use ID = 3, 4 or 5 - you don't get all features listed. All features must be listed exactly once, regardless of users who voted for it and whose id you use. - take a look http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c3d10/10

Comment: My other comment didn't make sense.  I was able to get the results you are looking for and I removed the previous incorrect SQL and posted only the working code and results.  Using the userid inside the left join did the trick.

Comment: Actually this whole question is a bit of a mess and complicated to explain but your query now does produce desired result and it looks simple enough. Thanks - excellent job.

Answer (score 2):

this should do it:

```
SELECT tmp1.id, name, votecnt, user_id, user_name FROM 
(SELECT *,(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM votes WHERE votes.featureid=features.id) AS "votecnt" FROM features) as tmp1
LEFT JOIN (SELECT features.id as feature_id, users.id as user_id, users.name as user_name FROM features
JOIN votes ON votes.featureid=features.id
JOIN users ON users.id=votes.userid
WHERE users.id=3) as tmp2 on tmp1.id = tmp2.feature_id
```

probably it's not the prettiest sql, and most likely there's also room for optimization

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it is good work and it does produce the desired output. However I accepted Vinnie's answer as his version looks more optimized and requires 2 steps less in SQL execution plan so it could be a bit faster. Thanks for the working result and the given effort, much appreciated!